# WPF - AvalonDock - Closing Document

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dispose, docking

I use AvalonDock with MVVM in a WPF project.

When I hit the "X" (Close button of the tab) my document closes but stays in memory. It seems that it is only hidden. It is not removed from my `Model.Documents` collection.

If I add `DockingManager_DocumentClosing` and try to remove my document from the collection, I receive an Exception in the following method of `Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutContent` because `parentAsContainer` is null.

```
/// <summary>
/// Close the content
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Please note that usually the anchorable is only hidden (not closed). By default when user click the X button it only hides the content.</remarks>
public void Close()
{
    var root = Root;
    var parentAsContainer = Parent as ILayoutContainer;
    parentAsContainer.RemoveChild(this);
    if (root != null)
        root.CollectGarbage();
    OnClosed();
}
```

Does anybody know how I could manage document in AvalonDock that can be removed from my `Model.Documents` in order to be eventually be disposed when I hit its `Close` button?

For reference: This is my XAML of the AvalonDock:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager
    x:Name="DockingManager" 
    DocumentsSource="{Binding DocumentItems}"  
    ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveMainWindowViewModel,
        Converter={StaticResource RestrictedClassConverter},
        ConverterParameter={x:Type multiSimAnalysis:MainWindowViewModel},
        Mode=TwoWay}"
    DocumentClosing="DockingManager_DocumentClosing"
    ActiveContentChanged="DockingManager_ActiveContentChanged">

  <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
    <pane:PanesStyleSelector>
      <pane:PanesStyleSelector.MainWindowViewLcStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
          <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
          <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
        </Style>
      </pane:PanesStyleSelector.MainWindowViewLcStyle>
    </pane:PanesStyleSelector>
  </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>

  <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
    <multiSimAnalysis:PanesTemplateSelector>
      <multiSimAnalysis:PanesTemplateSelector.MainWindowLcTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <multiSimAnalysis:MainWindowViewLc /> 
        </DataTemplate>
      </multiSimAnalysis:PanesTemplateSelector.MainWindowLcTemplate>
    </multiSimAnalysis:PanesTemplateSelector>
  </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

  <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
    <avalonDock:VS2010Theme/>
  </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
  <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="400">
        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Scope(s) selection" x:Name="PanelScopeSelection" IsVisible="True">
          <scopeSelection:UserControlSelectStudyScope x:Name="ToolScopeSelection"/>
        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
      </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
      <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
      <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150">
        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Properties" x:Name="PanelScopePropertyGrid">
          <!--<multiSimAnalysis:UserControlPropertyGrid x:Name="ToolPropertyGrid"  />-->
          <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="ToolPropertyGrid" SelectedObject="{Binding ActiveObject}" />
        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
      </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
  </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: The way it is generally handled is in the `Model.CloseCommand` (look at the XAML) so the when the Close command is executed, the document would remove itself from the collection. However, the document needs a reference to the documents collection in order to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually find an unacceptable workaround.
It is really twisted.

I only give that as reference. There should be a clean way to do it.

```
    // ************************************************************************
    private void DockingManager_DocumentClosing(object sender, Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DocumentClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Document.CanClose = false;

        DocumentModel documentModel = e.Document.Content as DocumentModel;
        if (documentModel != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Model.DocumentItems.Remove(documentModel)), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix this if you aren't using MVVM?

Comment: This is a long shot, but this event is never called for me, does anyone else have a similar experience?

Comment: @Mårten, I do not use AvalonDock anymore. I use Actipro Docking.

Comment: @EricOuellet where should I write/override this method?

Comment: @Daniel, there should be an event on the DockingManager named "DocumentClosing" that should occurs before the document close. This is more than 3 years old... perhaps the interface has changed? We are using ActiPro docking actually but you have to pay for.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that on a `LayoutDocument` or a `LayoutAnchorablePane`, applying both this setting works: `CanClose="False"` or `CanFloat="False"`.

It removes the Close button.

```
<avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Board"
                           ContentId="Board"
                           CanClose="False"
                           CanFloat="False">
</avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

Register for IsVisibleChanged.

```
void layoutFPR_Hidden(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LayoutAnchorable window = (LayoutAnchorable)sender;
    YourClass content = window.Content as YourClass;

    // Close the object
    content = null;
    ((LayoutAnchorable)sender).Close();

}
```