# AvalonDock with MVVM, document close doesn't remove i tem in the DocumentsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I have bound the `DocumentsSource` of the AvalonDock's `DockingManager` to an ObservableCollection of my ViewModels, following the article [AvalonDock 2.0 with MVVM](http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/AvalonDock-2.0-with-MVVM).

Adding a ViewModel to my collection opens correctly adds it in a new tab, but while I expected it to be removed from the collection if I close the tab from the UI, it's not the case: the collection keeps its previous count of VMs, being desynchronized with the opened tabs.

How can I have the VM removed from the collection when the tab is closed? The article just adds a `IsClosed` bound property to the ViewModel, but I would find more logical to just remove it from the collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - AvalonDock - Closing Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359818/wpf-avalondock-closing-document)

Comment: @Massimiliano Not really duplicate, as the mentioned question is about a crash, but it led me to the DocumentClosed delegate solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DocumentsSource` collection isn't really bound in two-way, I had to subscribe the `DockingManager.DocumentClosed` to a delegate that removes the ViewModel from the collection:

```
private void DocumentClosed(object sender, DocumentClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the VM associated with the closed document
    var documentVM = (ViewModel) e.Document.Content;
    var mainVM = (MainViewModel) DataContext;

    // Remove it from the tabs
    mainVM.Tabs.Remove(documentVM );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had been trying to figure this out for a very long time before I stumbled on your answer.

Comment: Oh my, I hadn't even noticed I had this problem, but I'm glad to have caught this early. Thanks a lot!